# how to run magento 2 command on live server bin/magento

Tags: magento

how to run command on bin/magento folder.

module:enable Infortis_Base Infortis_Brands Infortis_Cgen Infortis_Dataporter Infortis_Infortis Infortis_Ultimo Infortis_UltraMegamenu Infortis_UltraSlideshow